# Getting the name of control sequence token - which values of \escapechar besides 32 require special attention?

Tags: tex-core, strings, parameters, primitives

I'd like to get the name of a control sequence token as sequence of character tokens.

With `\relax` I'd like to get `relax`.

The preceeding escape character is to be removed from the result of `\string\relax`.

One can probably do

```
\def\gobble#1{}%
\expandafter\gobble\string\relax
```

But do I understand correctly?:

Actually behavior of `\string` depends on the value of the integer parameter `\escapechar`.

If `\escapechar` < 0  or `\escapechar` > 255/1114111 no escape character is prepended by `\string`.

If value of `\escapechar` is 32, then space token (charcode 32, catcode 10) is prepended by `\string`.
Space token cannot be handled as undelimited argument. So we have a case that needs special handling.

In all other cases character token is prepended with character code=value of `\escapechar` and category code=12/other.

So if you cannot rely on `\escapechar=92` you need to do like this:

```
\lowercase{\def\spacetokengobble} {}%
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\empty{}
\csname\ifnum\escapechar<0 empty\else
          \ifnum\escapechar=32 spacetokengobble\else
            \ifnum\expandafter\ifx\csname XeTeXrevision\endcsname\relax
                  \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax
                   255\else 1114111\fi\else 1114111\fi<\escapechar
            empty\else gobble\fi
          \fi
       \fi
       \expandafter
\endcsname\string\relax
```

Question:

With the value of `\escapechar`, besides the value 32, are there more special values where removing cannot be done by `\gobble`?

Comment: Besides invalid values, I think only 32 requires special attention because `\string` makes space characters have catcode 10, which is ignored by TeX when grabbing arguments.  I suggest you take a look at `expl3`'s `\cs_to_str:N`: it does precisely what you want

Comment: only 32 (space) is special but probably no one has ever done that:-) but you can set it to -1 and use `\string` then there is no need to gobble anything, as you say,or do you really need an expandable construct here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I intend to use it inside `\csname..\endcsname` to extend a macro name by a prefix before defining the macro. So I **think** an expandable solution is needed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik i started out with TeXbook two months ago. expl3 is inscrutable to me, sorry.

Comment: Using LuaTeX, the behavior of `\string` also depends on the age of the LuaTeX-engine in use. E.g., [with LuaTeX older than luatex 1.10.0 in texlive 2019 the behavior of `\string` is not well defined for values of `\escapechar` exceeding 1114111](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437465/118714).

Comment: @JamieLittleJoeHossAdamBen "expl3 is inscrutable to me, sorry."  I felt the same when I started using expl3.  But you get used to the syntax quickly. ;-)

Comment: @JamieLittleJoeHossAdamBen Your approach works fine, so if you wrap it into a definition it should work.  The `expl3` implementation, `_` and `:` removed for your convenience, is `\chardef\czeroint=0
\def\cstostr{\romannumeral\if\string\ \cstostrw\fi\expandafter\cstostrN\string}
\def\cstostrN#1{\czeroint}
\def\cstostrw#1\cstostrN{-\number\fi\expandafter\czeroint}`.  Use as `\cstostr\macro`.

Comment: if your main intention is to define a macro, then that definition isn't expandable anyway why restrict the logic to being inside `\csname`??  look how latex2e defines `\newcomand` and friends, before processing the argument it does `\begingroup \escapechar\m@ne...`  so `\string` acts in a known way.

Comment: @JamieLittleJoeHossAdamBen In LuaTeX, there is `\csstring` primitive which does the same as `\string` but without any escapechar. The `\escapechar` with `\string` is bad concept which brings only problems for macro programmers. If you are using modern TeX engine LuaTeX then you can throw these problems behind your hand and focus to real problems you are solving. The `\csstring` primitive is menitoned in tex-nuthsell.pdf and in LuaTeX manual, for example.

Comment: Link to related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12508/how-to-get-the-string-with/12515#12515